# How to convert numeric field (size: 10) to character field (size: 7)

Tags: sql

How can i do to convert numeric field (size: 10) to character field (size: 7) ..?
Thx.

Comment: you cannot do this without loosing 3 numbers...

Answer (score 0):

Depends on DBMS Oracle: TO_CHAR() , SQL Server str(). These are formating functions. For plain type conversion you can use cast

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL it is possible to do something like this:

```
RIGHT(CAST(intvalue AS char), 7)
```

If the integer value is greater than `9,999,999`, you will lose the highest order digits, of course.